# no style library in SharePoint site collection, can't reference XSL file

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm trying to follow this tutorial right here
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Integrate-a-Slider-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-Part-3-Integration-with-the-CQWP.aspx

to put a sliding carousel on my sharepoint site, however my sharepoint site is something like

```
https://www.sharepointsite.com/OPS/CCC/Sandbox
```

Now, the root site has a Style Library but none of the subsites have one. So when I reference XSL files for a web part, I get the following error

```
The web part references an untrusted XSL file. Only XSL files contained in this site's Style Library may be referenced.
```

The way I'm referencing the XSL file is like this

```
<property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">sites/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Slider/ItemStyle.xsl</property>
```

Is there a better way to reference it? Or can I create a Style Library within the Sandbox subsite?

Comment: Try enabling the Publishing feature at the Site level.

Answer (score 0):

I used this path and it worked

```
/sites/OPS/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/<filename>.xsl
```